# Determining the default database charset and collation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

In *MySQL*, what is the best way of programmatically retrieving the character set and the collation of the current database?

Is the following:

```sql
SELECT 
    default_character_set_name, default_collation_name
FROM
    information_schema.SCHEMATA
WHERE
    SCHEMA_NAME = SCHEMA()
```

identical to the below example?

```
select @@character_set_database, @@collation_database
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> [character_set_database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_database)
>
> ...
>
> The character set used by the default
>   database. The server sets this variable whenever the default database
>   changes. If there is no default database, the variable has the same
>   value as [character_set_server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_server).
>
> ...

and

> [collation_database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_collation_database)
>
> ...
>
> The collation used by the default database. The
>   server sets this variable whenever the default database changes. If
>   there is no default database, the variable has the same value as
>   [collation_server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_collation_server).
>
> ...

with both sentences would obtain the same result:

```sql
SELECT 
    default_character_set_name, default_collation_name
FROM
    information_schema.SCHEMATA
WHERE
    SCHEMA_NAME = SCHEMA()
```

and

```sql
select @@character_set_database, @@collation_database
```

demonstrated in the following test:

```sql
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `my_database`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT SCHEMA();
+----------+
| SCHEMA() |
+----------+
| NULL     |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   @@SESSION.character_set_database,
    ->   @@SESSION.collation_database,
    ->   @@SESSION.character_set_server,
    ->   @@SESSION.collation_server;
+----------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+
| @@SESSION.character_set_database | @@SESSION.collation_database | @@SESSION.character_set_server | @@SESSION.collation_server |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+
| latin1                           | latin1_swedish_ci            | latin1                         | latin1_swedish_ci          |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `my_database`
    -> CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    -> COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT SCHEMA();
+----------+
| SCHEMA() |
+----------+
| NULL     |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   @@SESSION.character_set_database,
    ->   @@SESSION.collation_database,
    ->   @@SESSION.character_set_server,
    ->   @@SESSION.collation_server;
+----------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+
| @@SESSION.character_set_database | @@SESSION.collation_database | @@SESSION.character_set_server | @@SESSION.collation_server |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+
| latin1                           | latin1_swedish_ci            | latin1                         | latin1_swedish_ci          |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE `my_database`;
Database changed

mysql> SELECT SCHEMA();
+-------------+
| SCHEMA()    |
+-------------+
| my_database |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   @@SESSION.character_set_database,
    ->   @@SESSION.collation_database,
    ->   @@SESSION.character_set_server,
    ->   @@SESSION.collation_server;
+----------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+
| @@SESSION.character_set_database | @@SESSION.collation_database | @@SESSION.character_set_server | @@SESSION.collation_server |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+
| utf8mb4                          | utf8mb4_general_ci           | latin1                         | latin1_swedish_ci          |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME`,
    ->   `DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME`
    -> FROM
    ->   `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA`
    -> WHERE
    ->   SCHEMA_NAME = SCHEMA();
+----------------------------+------------------------+
| DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME | DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME |
+----------------------------+------------------------+
| utf8mb4                    | utf8mb4_general_ci     |
+----------------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

however, a union of both sentences would not be wrong:

```sql
mysql> USE `my_database`;
Database changed

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME`,
    ->   `DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME`
    -> FROM
    ->   `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA`
    -> WHERE
    ->   SCHEMA_NAME = SCHEMA() AND
    ->   `DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME` = @@SESSION.character_set_database AND
    ->   `DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME` = @@SESSION.collation_database;
+----------------------------+------------------------+
| DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME | DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME |
+----------------------------+------------------------+
| utf8mb4                    | utf8mb4_general_ci     |
+----------------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```